# Duda sobre cadenas y funciones JAVA

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un programa que al meterle 10 cadenas en un array, diga cual es la cadena más corta mediante una función y la muestre. Tengo como comienzo algo así. Gracias.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena[] = new String [10];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
      System.out.println("Escriba la cadena número" + i + ".");
      cadena [i]= teclado.nextLine();
    }

    teclado.close();
}
```

Comment: Me equivoqué al redactarlo, ahora está bien escrito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas Jose antonio bienvenido a la comunidad, lo que buscas es algo así

```
   public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cadena[] = new String [10];
    int i;
    String cadenaP = "inicial";

    for (i=0;i<9;i++) {
      System.out.println("Escriba la cadena número" + i + ".");
      cadena [i]= teclado.nextLine();
      if(i==0)
      cadenaP = cadena[i];
      if(cadena[i].length() < cadenaP.length())
        cadenaP = cadena[i];
    }

    teclado.close();
    System.out.println("La cadena más corta ha sido: " + cadenaP + ".");
}
```

Si quieres ponerlo en una función a parte simplemente sería recorrer el array como haces con el bucle y aplicar las condiciones.

Comment: vlae, gracias Tomás.